# 6N137 Optocoupler Maximum Voltage on the Diode Side

Tags: opto-isolator

I want to use the 6N137 optocouler to read a +18/-18 volt signal and read the 6N137's output using an arduino. The circuit I want to use is shown here: https://github.com/Laserlicht/MaerklinMotorola

I fail to understand how much voltage the 6N137 can handle before it breaks. In the datasheet by Vishay, I found that the 6N137 can take at most 7V for it's operating voltage. But I cannot find the maximum allowed voltage on the input side (pins 2 and 3)!

My question is, can I safely connect a +18/-18 volt signal to the pins 2 and 3 of the 6N137? What is the maximum voltage it will survive? Does it matter how much voltage is put into pins 2 and 3?

I am a beginner and I do not understand optocouplers very well, so maybe I am completely misunderstanding the entire point of the 6N137. I already destroyed a 6N137 so I am trying to figure out what went wrong. Maybe someone can explain this to me.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [6N137 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84732/6n137.pdf) page 2, under "Absolute Maximum Ratings", we find two values, \$V_R = 5V\$ and \$I_F = 20mA\$.

\$V_R\$ is labelled "Reverse input voltage". This is the maximum voltage you may apply across the LED in reverse bias. That is, the LED cathode may never be more than 5V more positive than the anode. Beyond this the diode will break down (like a zener diode does), and possibly suffer damage.

A simple series resistor will not suffice to protect the LED in such a condition. If you expect that your input signal polarity might reverse, and expose the LED to more than 5V reverse bias, then you must take measures to protect the LED from such a condition yourself. This may be as simple as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbetf4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You must not connect a ±18V source to the input (pins 2 and 3) without a current limiting resistor R1, and reverse bias protection diode D1. If D1 is absent, then when IN is at −18V, which is 18V *below* cathode C, the LED is reverse biased beyond its 5V tolerance. With D1 in place, such a condition will forward bias D1, which will clamp the voltage across it a maximum of 0.7V or so, preventing the LED from being exposed to the full 18V.

D1, when forward biased, will never have more than 0.7V across it. The forward biased LED will have a maximum of 1.7V across it (page 4, \$V_F\$, "Input forward voltage"). Since at any instant, one or the other of these two diodes will be forward biased, neither will ever be reverse biased sufficiently to break down.

\$I_F = 20mA\$ tells you what maximum *average* current the LED can tolerate when forward biased. If you placed a potential difference of 18V across the LED (between pins 2 and 3, such that node A is 18V *positive* with respect to node C), then the LED would attempt to clamp the voltage across it to a maximum of \$V_F\$, and the amount of current that would flow would be limited only by the impedance of the 18V source. Since this could be many amps, and could easily destroy the LED, you must include R1 to limit forward current.

To calculate a value for R1, you first must decide what current you wish to flow, when your input is +18V. Let's say you want \$I_F=10mA\$, well within the 6N137's tolerance of 20mA. The voltage \$V_{R1}\$ across R1 will be the difference between the source voltage \$V_{IN}=18V\$ and the voltage \$V_F=1.4V\$ (typical) across the LED. This will determine current according to Ohm's law:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= I_F \times R_1 \\ \\
R_1 &= \frac{V_{R1}}{I_F} \\ \\
&= \frac{V_{IN}-V_F}{I_F} \\ \\
&= \frac{18V - 1.4V}{10mA} \\ \\
&= \frac{16.6V}{10mA} \\ \\
&= 1660\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

When \$V_{IN}=-18V\$, then it is D1 that is forward biased, and passes all current. Its own voltage will be 0.7V, instead of 1.4V, and you can calculate the current that flows through D1 in the same way, using Ohm's law.

Answer (score 1):

The input of a [6N137](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/6N137%20Series.pdf) is an (infrared) LED, just as the symbol implies:

[image]

It's much like a visible LED except that it has a lower Vf (more like 1.2V-1.5V than 2-3V). It has a maximum reverse voltage that the manufacturer specifies (5V). It has a maximum **current** (25mA  at 25°C).

So you need a circuit (which can be as simple as a series resistor) to limit the current in most cases. For example, for 18V, there will be about 16.5V across the resistor. If we pick a current such as 12mA which is well above the 5mA threshold current, but well below the 25mA maximum, the resistor is easily found from Ohm's law, about 1.3kΩ and the power dissipation will be a couple hundred mW.

If you could apply reverse voltage to the resistor + input then you should protect the LED with a diode, either in series with the LED + resistor, or in parallel with just the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyWlPw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>